# How to convert â€™ to apostrophe in C#?

Tags: c#

I have tried several combinations of ASCII, Latin1, Windows-1252, UTF-8 and Unicode to convert â€™ to apostrophe in C#, but to no avail.

```
byte[] uBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(questionString);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, uBytes);
string converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

I am using this conversion chart to discover what each code should be: http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Comment: Can you show the source code you have?

Comment: There is no `â€™` and no apostrophe. There are only bytes, and encodings (and "Unicode" is *not* an encoding btw) which map them to characters. As a wrong choice for the latter seems to cause your trouble, I'd forget about that layer for a second and look at the former (lower) layer. Which bytes do you have, where do they come from, and how does your program get at them?

Comment: This sounds like an encoding problem that can be fixed at the root

Comment: Start by reading this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: looking at an ascii map table â€™ may be interpreted as the ascii representation of the sequence of bytes %E2 %80 %99, which is an utf8 byte sequence for an apostrophe. What is your default encoding ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Try](https://compilify.net/1sq) the following:

```
var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("â€™");
var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: Thank you.  My misunderstanding was that the characters were actually already UTF8.  I appreciate you answering the question instead of trying to prove how smart you are by posting links, etc. as above.